# UI(regression) Test Naming Convention Recommendation

Tags: regression, naming

I am looking for recommendations on naming conventions for UI tests. I am using Given-When-Then pattern for naming unit tests.  This works well for unit tests because I am using unit test to test a single thing.

However when it comes to UI (regression) tests this is not working very well.  I write a UI test to test a particular user flow that may have many steps.  I will have a test for a happy path and one or more unhappy path.  I am looking for some recommendations on regression tests naming

For example, I have a regression test that goes through the checkout process for an ecommerce website. User will add items to cart, go through the checkout process by entering billing shipping info, credit card information, order review and confirmation.

What are recommendations for when users is able to place an order, when user enters invalid credit card number and get card rejected